# bazel action to invoke py_binary

Tags: python, bazel, rules

I have a python program that takes 2 command line arguments and execute the logic to do desired action. And I'm generating a executable by using py_binary for python program.  I want to have a bazel rule to invoke the py_binary and pass 2 command line arguments to that rule by calling it from where ever I want.

//example/Build   : py_binary:

```
py_binary(
  name = "py_pgm",
  srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
  main = "main.py",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

examples/defs.bzl:

```
def _impl(ctx): 
           ctx.action( 
                             ) 
ex_rule= rule( 
            implementation = _impl, 
             attrs = {  } )
```

I need a rule to invoke the "example"

application/Build:

```
load('//examples:defs.bzl', 'ex_rule')

ex_rule(
     name:run
     args = device_name and file path
)
```

Can someone help me with the bazel rule to invoke py_binary. I looked online for some hints but the ones present are from 2016 and many of the logics are deprecated so I couldn't get anything to work.
Referred Sources:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1147
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1192

If someone can help me with the rule it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
genrule(
  name = "run_my_thing",
  srcs = ["//example:py_pgm"],
  outs = ["fractal.pgm"],
  cmd = "$(location //example:py_pgm) output $@"
)
```

https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule

Your question didn't include any explanation of why you need a rule that runs a command. Everything in the BUILD file exists to create some output from some input, so in my example, I have it producing "fractal.pgm".

Comment: To add, if all that needs to be done is run the py_binary, you can do `bazel run //example:py_pgm`

Comment: Thank you Nick and ahumesky for your response.